# UI design app for programmers

Tags: website-design

I am looking to do some basic UI elements for my website, eg a logo. I am not looking for anything really fancy, something like:

[image]
<sub>(source: [37signals.com](https://37signals.com/images/logo-37s-large.png))</sub>

and this sort of things.

Besides photoshop, was program do you guys recommend where I can do this things easily.

I am using Mac, native Mac apps are more than welcome.

Comment: This question title is a bit misleading. "Design for UI" would be more accurate than "UI design" (which generally refers to IA, IxD, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Art Text](http://www.belightsoft.com/products/arttext/overview.php) by BeLight Software.  It lets you create glassy buttons, stylized text, and icons in different styles.  [MacUpdate Promo](https://www.mupromo.com/deal/1331/art-text) happens to be running a 30% discount on it till the end of the week.

There is also [Aquatint](http://www.sticksoftware.com/software/Aquatint.html), but it requires that Rosetta be installed before you can run it on Intel-based Macs.  It's really old.

A favorite of mine (though it doesn't manipulate text like Art Text) is PhotoStyler.  It lets you create all sorts of effects.  It's perfect for the Photoshop-challenged, like me.  The publisher, [Corner-A](http://corner-a.com/), also makes other apps that you might find helpful.

And last but not least, check out Apple's list of [Imaging & 3D apps](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/imaging_3d/).

Comment: Awesome thank ArtText did the trick, I did a simple text baner with a small drawing in 2 hours, enough to show the idea :).

Answer (score 3):

Illustrator. use ilustrator to design a logo. Perhaps Inkscape, but make sure it goes well as vector shapes without gradients. You might want to consider how to scale / amend it to use it as a favicon bitmap, hence 16x16 px.

If you want to have it long-lasting, ask an expert – folks are spending years to study graphic design – not without a reason.

Comment: Illustrator. I tried Inkscape for a while and found it a bit clumsy in comparison to Illustrator.

Comment: +1 for doing logos in vector.   And also that design is not about about the program but the person's skill set.  You could go out and spend $1000s on the best software and still make a logo that looks like a turd.

Answer (score 1):

Some open source options:
http://www.gimp.org/
http://inkscape.org/

Answer (score 1):

The best App besides Fireworks and Photoshop is Pixelmator IMHO

Answer (score 0):

I'd second Fireworks. It's designed specifically for web graphics and is a nice blend of raster and vector.

The GIMP is a bit wonky on my snow leopard as everything requires a double-click for some reason.

Inkscape is a nice open source alternative to Adobe Illustrator.

Photoshop is a beast and expensive, but obviously widely used. I've been meaning to check out Pixelmator.

As for 'easy to use' well, they all have learning curves.

Answer (score 0):

I am going out on a limb here, but I would guess that your problem isn't what application to use but the creative process itself.  I have a lot of engineers and other friends who make their own logos and I end up throwing out the design and starting from scratch.

Do you have a design already sketched out?